# Chart.js, URL to retrieve data by userId

Tags: angular, url, chart.js

I want to display information from each user in a chart, by using userId. Something like this:

```
private baseUrl = `http://localhost:9009/debt/getdebt/${userId}`;
```

With this code though I get error saying ''*Cannot find name 'userId''*, it only works if I hard code it with a specific userId (e.g 111):

```
e.g private baseUrl = `http://localhost:9009/debt/getdebt/111
```

My service **debt-service** can GET by userId but I don't understand how to make the **chart-service** with the baseUrl correct. I followed a tutorial on Youtbue that got me displaying the chart, but I'm stuck now after having to change this url-path. Any advice on how to move forward?

**debt-service**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { Debt } from '../models/debt';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DebtServiceService {
  debts: Array<Debt> = [];
  debtObject: BehaviorSubject<Array<Debt>> = new BehaviorSubject(this.debts);


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  //GET debt by userId
  byUserId(userId): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`http://localhost:9009/debt/getdebt/${userId}`)
  }
}
```

**chart-service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ChartServiceService {
  private baseUrl = `http://localhost:9009/debt/getdebt/111`;

  constructor(private http:  HttpClient) { }

  debts() { 
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}`
    return this.http.get(url).toPromise().then((data) => {
      return data
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Sorry if I've been unclear. I want to display the information retrieved from each user, by the userId. I can only display the information now if I hard code the user Id (e.g 111). I'll have multiple user Id's though so I can't have the url hard coded like that. I need something like ${userId} but I'm not sure how to implement it correctly